# Share cluster in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

Let's have a cluster made by `makeCluster` function.
Does it need same type of synchronization like barrier/semaphore synchronization? Or I can run code in parallel (for example, by parLapply) from different section of code runned parallely?

Thank you.

P.S. a little example (something like that).

```
func1 <- function(count, cl)
{
parSapply(cl, 1:count, function(i) { i^count; });
}

func2 <- function(cl1, cl2, count)
{
    clusterExport(cl1, cl2);
    parLapply(cl1, 1:count, function(i) { func1(i, cl2); });
}

maxThreads <- 4;
cl1 <- makeCluster(4);
cl2 <- makeCluster(4);

func2(cl1, cl2);
```

Comment: Typically what this parallel functions in R do is take 1 computation and run parts of it simultaneously on different cores, then combine the results in a manner that you've specified. It's not for running different sections of your code at the same time. You could do that with or without a cluster by using multiple R sessions.

Comment: Emmm... Let's look hypotetic situation: I have 2 clusters cl1 and cl2. I run same code on cl1 and this code consists the part which are executed on cl2. So, should I synchronize my code execution via semaphore (for example) or not?

Comment: This is a bit unclear to me. Could you include the code for a reproducible example in your question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve